# Values printing in pairs issue? Lua

Tags: arrays, class, printing, lua, lua-table

For some reason the countries that seem to be returned are all returning in pairs? How can you change the code so it only returns the countries in 'Europe' once?

```
function newcountry(continent,country)
  local object = {}
  object.continent = continent
  object.country = country

  local list = {}

  for i in pairs( object ) do
   if object.continent == "Europe" then
     table.insert(list, object.country)
     print(object.country)

  end
end

  return object
end


a = newcountry("Africa","Algeria")
b = newcountry("Europe","England")
c = newcountry("Europe","France")
d = newcountry("Europe","Spain")
e = newcountry("Asia","China")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this code, but to answer your question:

```
function newcountry(continent,country)
    local object = {}
    object.continent = continent
    object.country = country
    local list = {}
    if object.continent == "Europe" then
        table.insert(list, object.country)
        print(object.country)
    end
    return object
end
```

This code will print countries in Europe just once. When there was loop in there, it printed name of the country twice, because it did it for each element of `object` table (`continent` and `country`, hence two times).

[Generic for loops](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html) in *Programming in Lua* (first edition).

I would also like to point out that `list` is quite useless at the moment. It is not being returned and stays local. On top of that, every time you call `newcountry` there is **new** `list` created. They are all unique - country objects are **not** added to single list. But again - I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.